# Creating reusable widgets

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, render, renderpartial

I`m using asp.net mvc 2.0 and trying to create reusable web site parts, that can be added at any page dynamically.
The problem I have is how to load a partial view with all related js and data? Ive tried the following ways to do that:

1. Use partial view and put all the js into it. In main view use render partial. But to initialize partial view I need to add model to current action method model to be able to make `RenderPartial("MyPartialView", Model.PartialViewModel)`.
   Also I do not have a place to put additional data I need to fill my form(like drop down lists values, some predefined values etc).
2. Use RenderAction, but it seems it have same problems as RenderPartial, except for I do not need to add anything to any other model.

Any other oprions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, RenderAction performs the full pipeline on the action, then renders the result - so what is rendered is the same as what you'd see if you'd browsed to the action.

I've used RenderAction to render 'widgets' throughout a site, but in my view they should be independent of the page rendering them, otherwise they're not really widgets and should be part of the rendering page's code instead. For instance, if there's a log in form, you will always take the user to a page that can process the information, no matter what page they are currently on, so this makes for a good widget. Other ways I've used it is to show a shopping basket or advertising. Neither of which are dependent on the page being shown.

Hope this helps a little!

Comment: Carl, so which way should I go? How can I populate data needed for e.g. dropdown list? Where should all markup + js go?

Comment: Populate it in the controller for the action for the widget. The markup goes in a partial view and the JS in the master pages (unless you're using razor where you can then put it in the partial view). - To be clear, you need an action and a view for the widget, and you call the action using RenderAction.